# Adding elements to a list<class> within a dictionary modifies all variables already stored

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I think I must be missing some basic of how C# works.
I do have a list within a structure, used as value of a dictionary.
However, whenever I add new objects to the dictionary all variables already stored in the dictionary change. 
I am evidently creating objects with the same reference, just thought I was not :P, therefore I am not sure how to fix it.
Following is the relevant code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DizClass diz = new DizClass();

            Group tempG = new Group();

            tempG.Category = 1;
            tempG.Chiave = "A";

            diz.Add(tempG);

            tempG.Category = 2;
            tempG.Chiave = "B";

            diz.Add(tempG);

            tempG.Category = 3;
            tempG.Chiave = "A";

            diz.Add(tempG);

            diz.Print();
        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Group
    {
        public string Chiave { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
    }

    struct Host_Struct
    {
        public string variableStr;
        public List<Group> lista;
    }

    class DizClass
    {
        Dictionary<string, Host_Struct> diz = new Dictionary<string, Host_Struct>();

        public void Add(Group gr)
        {
            if (diz.ContainsKey(gr.Chiave))
            {
                diz[gr.Chiave].lista.Add(gr);
            }
            else
            {
                Host_Struct tempHS = new Host_Struct(){ lista = new List<Group>() { gr } };
                diz.Add(gr.Chiave, tempHS);
            }
        }

        public void Print() {
            foreach (string Key in diz.Keys) foreach (Group val in diz[Key].lista) Debug.Print("{0} - {1}", Key, val.Category);
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to obtain:

- A - 1
- A - 3
- B - 2

Whereas I get:

- A - 3
- A - 3
- B - 3

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You are creating the instance just once with `Group tempG = new Group();` from there on you are just changing the values inside the same instance and storing the same instance in different dictionary entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list just stores a reference to the "Group"-Object. You add the same "Group" 3 times and change it in between.

Fix:

```
        Group tempG = new Group();
        tempG.Category = 1;
        tempG.Chiave = "A";

        diz.Add(tempG);

        tempG = new Group();
        tempG.Category = 2;
        tempG.Chiave = "B";

        diz.Add(tempG);

        tempG = new Group();
        tempG.Category = 3;
        tempG.Chiave = "A";

        diz.Add(tempG);
```

Answer (score 2):

You working with object orientation.

You only create one object and add this object in 3 times.

```
Group tempG = new Group();

...

diz.Add(tempG);
```

Try this:

```
Group tempG1 = new Group();

tempG1.Category = 1;
tempG1.Chiave = "A";

diz.Add(tempG1);

Group tempG2 = new Group();

tempG2.Category = 2;
tempG2.Chiave = "B";

diz.Add(tempG2);

...

diz.Print();
```

I recommend you to read about object-oriented programming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as a matter of fact the same approach I used here would work just fine in C++ (which is OO). It seems then that C# Lists do not create Obj copies but just save refs.

Comment: I'm gonna elaborate on this answer a little bit. The reason this is performing the way you have coded it is because you are declaring one instance of the Group class, once you add this object to the list you are storing its *reference* in the list, so whenever you change the object's members all references to it will still be pointing to the same object, adding it back in again just adds another reference to the object. If you want them all to be different, you need a new reference to a new object for each entry.